# How to use Command Prompt's Find function to find blank lines?

Tags: cmd

I am using find to filter through results of a NetSH WiFi scan. There are over 2000 entries and many of them are no SSID, so the line just looks like "SSID ##: ", where the number signs are a number 0-99. Also there are many lines that are just blank. My question is is there a way to make the find command not include those lines. I have tried `find /V ""` and many others (including -r-n, ^r^n, /r/n and other variations of newline characters)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
whatevercommand | findstr /v /r /c:"^$"
```

Use `findstr` to retrieve the lines that do not contain (`/v`) the regular expression `/r` : start of line (`^`) followed by end of line (`$`)

Comment: `whatevercommand | findstr /v "^$"` <--- for brevity.  findstr seems to default to regexp mode when there is a regexp character in the search term.

Comment: @foxidrive, I know it, thank you. It is just the habit of explicitly include how the command should behave. Especialy in the case of `findstr`. I dont like to see something like `findstr "."` and forget or don't realize it is a regular expression and not a literal. Just an habit.

Comment: I didn't even know that cmd had a 'findstr' command. This solves a lot of issues I have been having. Thanks!